# TinyMCE doesn't affect my orginal textarea

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am pointing below textarea with selector setting of TinyMCe and i see that TinyMCE hide it and construct new html structure for itself. Problem is when i post form there is no any change in orginal hided textarea. What i have to do for fix problem ?

```
<form action="#">
      <textarea name="body" class="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your full page (including CSS / Javascript) ? perhaps here -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php can you try it on orginal example ? Try to change something in editor and check orginal textarea. But in orginal page i see a submit button. The submit button handle a javascript event for affect orginal textarea ?

Comment: im sorry I don't understand what you mean - I can change something - click submit and my changes are posted and displayed - what are you trying to do ? what isnt working ?

Comment: Yes in orginal example value is posted. But why not in my example ?
In my own example, posted value is orginal textarea value and it is not refreshed unfortunality. My orginal code need to trash for post here. But i will try now.

Comment: @ManseUK - I am sorry i can not demonstrate it at jsfiddle.net because it has many dependency and dependencies loading at runtime from root of current domain.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` in order to get the content into the textarea!